# How can I set the Emscripten path in Vensim

Tags: emscripten, vensim

I am trying to create a webassembly out of an MDL file using Vensim. According to Vensim official guide, if I click on Tools->Options the following modal should pop up:

[image: The modal that should appear]

In this modal there is a label with which I can set the emscripten path. Unluckily the modal that appears is the following:

[image: The modal which appears]

This modal doesn't contain a label with which I can set the emscripten path.

Answer (score 0):

I need Vensim DSS to do this.

An alternative is to use SD Everywhere.